# Add Ionic Project within existing Angular Project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular9, ionic5

I have an existing angular project, in which I need to add an ionic project so that I can use `ionic serve` to run the ionic project and `ng serve` to run the angular project.

I tried using `ng add @ionic/angular` and after creating a project using `ionic init` when I try `ionic serve` this error is thrown `[ng] An unhandled exception occurred: Project does not exist.[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127). The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.`

Also tried this it doesn't work https://stack247.wordpress.com/2019/03/11/integrate-ionic-in-existing-angular-project/ 
Creates a new project folder for ionic which is not my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an NX Workspace to have multiple apps (e.g. Angular, Ionic) alongside each other. This would implement the following structure to your repository:

```
/apps
  /angular-app
    /src       <-- Same as in a default Angular project
    tsconfig.json
    etc.
  /ionic-app
    /src       <-- Same as in a default Ionic project
    tsconfig.json
    etc.
/libs          <-- Shareable code between apps and other libs
nx.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
etc.
```

To do so I would recommend to set up a completely new nx workspace by

```
npx create-nx-workspace NAME
```

replace NAME with your repository name and change your current directory to the newly created. It will ask you if you want to initialise a default application. You can pick an Angular application here and copy over all your Angular code. Then you can run

```
ng g @nrwl/angular:application ionic-app
```

followed by (if you have the ionic CLI installed, otherwise install it first by running `npm install -g @ionic/cli`)

```
ionic init "ionic-app" --type=angular
```

You'll need to add the following configuration in your **ionic.config.json** file inside the root directory

```json
{
  "name": "mobile",
  "integrations": {},
  "type": "angular",
  "root": "apps/ionic-app"
}
```

References:

- [Github NX, issue 619](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/619)
- [Github NX, issue 2633](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2633)
- [Medium: Ionic4 NestJS Nx Monorepo Dream come true](https://medium.com/@haleminh27/ionic-4-nestjs-nx-monorepo-dream-come-true-a7eb4c01a646)